# Query for selecting columns with repeated values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, distinct

I have a table with multiple records and multiple columns, something like:

```
Name       |Color      |Price       |Description |Code
-------------------------------------------------------------
Item1      |Blue       |$15.00      |ABCD        |Code1
Item2      |Blue       |$25.00      |ABCD        |Code2
Item3      |Blue       |$35.00      |ABCD        |Code2
Item4      |Blue       |$15.00      |ABCD        |Code1
Item5      |Blue       |$15.00      |ABCD        |Code1
```

I want to get, by using a query, the columns that have the same values throughout all the records, something like

```
Color      |Description 
------------------------------------
Blue       |ABCD        
Blue       |ABCD        
Blue       |ABCD        
Blue       |ABCD        
Blue       |ABCD
```

Is there any easy way to do that? I've been thinking on a way to  get this but no success so far. Can anyone help me to do this? Thanks!

Comment: which rdbms are you using oracle or mysql?

Comment: Microsoft SQL, but I would also like to know this for mysql.

Comment: name doesn't have the same value for all rows

Comment: Every output follows certain pattern to be drawn from the given input set. But I found yours as an exception.

Comment: what do u mean by "Same values throughout all records". As said, name,code,price doesn't have the same values in the output that you mentioned

Comment: You can access the schema, but you can also use UNION for this (although the formatting of the output will be a little different)

Comment: @liwuen we should consider only two columns (color and description) please confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql  (and oracle) you can use a subselect .. group bu and having

```
select * from my_table 
where (color, decription) in (select color, description 
                      from my_table 
                      group by color, description 
                      having count(*) >1)
```

Otherwise if you don't know id advance which colums are going to satisfy the criteria you can build a dinamic select for testing each column .

```
select my_column from my_table 
group by my_column
having count(*) >1
```

if the related select .. group by adn count(*) is >1 you have repeeated value

Comment: well if the  OP don't knwo the columns   he could build dinamic select for testing each column  ... if the related select .. group by adn count(*)  is >1

Comment: #@Strawberry  answer updated like you suggested .. thanks

Comment: And now it should be fairly obvious to the op how they might incorporate UNION so as to test all columns in a single go.

Comment: @Strawberry  correct .. yes .. the OP could easly incorporate several union for test the columns ..

Comment: Thank you guys! By using UNION I think I'm done. Thanks!